# calling a method with parameters

Tags: ios, mapkit

i`m using MapKit framework and i want to ask you about something :

```
+ (NSUInteger)zoomLevelForMapRect:(MKMapRect)mRect withMapViewSizeInPixels:(CGSize)viewSizeInPixels
{
    NSUInteger zoomLevel = MAXIMUM_ZOOM; // MAXIMUM_ZOOM is 20 with MapKit
    MKZoomScale zoomScale = mRect.size.width / viewSizeInPixels.width; //MKZoomScale is just a CGFloat typedef
    double zoomExponent = log2(zoomScale);
    zoomLevel = (NSUInteger)(MAXIMUM_ZOOM - ceil(zoomExponent));
    return zoomLevel;
}
```

this method..how can i know the value of `mRect` and `viewSizeInPixels` parameters to be able to call it?? thx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map view's current MKMapRect is the visibleMapRect property and the view size would be in frame.size (since MKMapView is a subclass of UIView) so the method would be called using something like:

```
NSUInteger zoomLevel = [UtilityClass 
                           zoomLevelForMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect 
                           withMapViewSizeInPixels:mapView.frame.size];
```

`UtilityClass` is whatever class that method is in and replace `mapView` with whatever you map view is actually named.

By the way, the [MapKit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) and the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) are worth looking at.

Comment: Thx for your help, by the way, with what value can i compare the zoomLevel variable to make sure that the user has actually zoomed out the map ?? thx

Comment: You could use the delegate methods regionWillChangeAnimated and regionDidChangeAnimated and compare the span before and after.